# Simple Binary Replacement

Tags: shell-script, grep, replace, text, binary

I tried using bbe as below

`bbe -e 's/01110011/01111000/' test.txt`

All I'm trying to accomplish in this example is to read the file as if it's a binary file, and replacing the letter `s` with `x`.

I'm open to alternative solutions, I'm not stuck on `bbe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, bbe cannot use **binary** (base 2) patterns directly.  Hexadecimal, octal, or decimal work, however:

```
# Hex:
$ echo 'xs' | bbe -e 's/\x73/\x78/'
xx
# Octal:
$ echo 'xs' | bbe -e 's/\0163/\0170/'
xx
# Decimal:
$ echo 'xs' | bbe -e 's/\115/\120/'
xx
```